# Rescaling an image just knowing a scale factor preserving aspect Ratio

Tags: c++, image-processing, resolution, rescale

Okay I know it sounds like it's a repost of another question, but I couldn't find anybody asking the same question as I do, or maybe I'm wrong because that's not the way how to handle the problem, but anyway here it comes:

I have an input image, say HD 1920*1080 and I just know a scale factor: say, 0.3  ( 30% of original size).
How would one compute the new target size that is close to 30% of the original, while keeping the aspect ratio ?
In other words how to rescale the image to 30% accurately?

If this makes no sense, please could you enlighten me about how to scale an image without knowing the target size and just knowing a scale factor?

Thanks

Ps: I'm using C/C++, but pseudo-code is okay

Comment: Huh?  Why isn't it just (1920 / 0.3) by (1080 / 0.3)?

Comment: +1 @Oli, but I think you mean `1920*0.3` by `1080*0.3`.

Comment: well okay, this resolution is fine for scale factor like this, but what if the result of originalSize * scaleFactor is a floating point? round to nearest?

Comment: Scale both dimensions. If you just tried it you'd see.

Comment: Also, what do you suppose "C/C++" is?

Comment: I tried it, if you add nothing useful please refrain from posting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your height & width are integers, you can just do this...

```
height = height * (int)(scaleFactor*100) / 100;
width  = width  * (int)(scaleFactor*100) / 100;
```

Alternatively, this solution also works for `int` but makes more sense with floating point vars...

```
height = floor(height * scaleFactor);
width  = floor(width  * scaleFactor);
```

Or, regardless of the variable types, you can just let the compiler worry about how to handle the rounding...

```
height = height * scaleFactor;
width  = width  * scaleFactor;
```

...but with that solution, you may get off-by-1 rounding errors from one platform to the next.  That may not matter in your use case, though.

Another possibility, if your `scaleFactor` is itself an `int` and (in this example) is 30%, then `scaleFactor` could be the value `30`, and you'd simply do this...

```
height = height * scaleFactor / 100;
width  = width  * scaleFactor / 100;
```

The key is that if you scale both your x & y coordinates by the same factor, you preserve the original aspect ratio.

Comment: thanks for your answer I'm going to try it

Comment: @Lex, my favorite, not listed here, would include some rounding and enforcing a minimum value: `height = max(1, (int)(height * scaleFactor + 0.5));`

Comment: thanks Mark, +0.5 is for rounding to nearest greater integer , right?

Comment: @Lex - I believe that's what Mark Ransom's suggestion's `+0.5` is for.  I don't actually think it matters that much when the difference is a single pixel, unless your resulting image is going to be really small, the difference is negligible.  But I suppose enforcing a minimum of 1 pixel might avoid divide-by-zero crashes in some cases.

Comment: @MarkRansom - Thanks for fixing my typos.

Comment: @Lex, yes +0.5 is to round to nearest rather than to floor. And phonetagger, you're welcome.